# ReactiveX Separate and join with `withLatestFrom`

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming

I have a sequence of events, they're either A or B in type, and I read this sequence out from a text file.

I create an observable with this sequence:

`A1-B-B-A2-B-B-B`

and filter them such that:

Astream = stream.filter(trueIfA)

Bstream = stream.filter(trueIfB)

```
A: A1-----A2------
B: --B-B-----B-B-B
```

But when I use `B.withLatestFrom(A,concat)`, I end up with:

```
A2B-A2B----A2B-A2B-A2B
```

Why is this the case? How can I manipulate it so I can get `A1B-A1B-A2B-A2B-A2B` sequence?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Observable.combineLatest()`, as you want to get latest emissions from both `Observable`s when any of them emits items.
`withLatestFrom()` operator is similar to `combineLatest`, but only emits items when the single source `Observable` ('B') emits an item, not when any of the `Observable`s that are passed to the operator do, as `combineLatest` does.
[source](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html)

Answer (score 1):

Beyond yosriz' answer, you also need `publish(Func1)` to multicast the original source:

```
Observable<T> source = ...

source.publish(o -> 
    Observable.combineLatest(o.filter(trueIfA), o.filter(trueIfB), 
        (a, b) -> concat))
.subscribe(...)
```

Comment: tried both solutions, but doesn't seem to have any effect, it seems that the which ever stream is on the right will always only contain the last element.

Comment: What are your sources exactly? Are they properly paced? If they are synchronous then indeed combineLatest won't work for you.

Comment: My source is an array, as in, I read every line into a List and create an Observable from that list. Would that be "synchronous"? I guess I expected the Rx APi to work on static data to enforce 'order' and a sense of 'time', but I might've been mistaken.

Comment: Your diagram indicates there is a time component but with arrays, there is none. Without time, how could you tell what's between A1 and A2?